# placeholder в input yii2

Tags: php, yii2, input, inputmask, placeholder

Как добавить placeholder в input widget yii2? 
Пробовал через texinput, но не катит, так как widget

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'dsaas'])->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                'mask' => '+9 999 999-99-99'
            ])->label(false) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'phone', [
           'inputOptions' => ['autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'class' => 'form-control transparent']
     ])->textInput()->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
                'mask' => '+9 999 999-99-99',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Your placeholder']
])->label(false); ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ он был для меня очень полезен